# taskdef class proguard.ant.ProGuardTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Tags: android, ant, android-5.0-lollipop

After upgrading my SDK to Android L, I encounter an problem when building android project by ant.

error output:

`/Users/dreamtale/develop/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:828: taskdef class proguard.ant.ProGuardTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]`

Anyone face the same problem?

Comment: 'fraid so : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

Comment: @NickT actually right, i download a proguard manually and copy the proguard-android.txt, Now it worked!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in the new update the tools directory does not contain the proguard folder anymore, and the build.xml script does not find the proguard jar file. 
Until an official fix is given, you can workaround this issue as following:

- donwload proguard from http://proguard.sourceforge.net/. I already had v 4.8 and it worked.
- unzip the proguard archive to {sdk.dir}/tools and rename the folder "proguard"
- try again

Comment: Thanks, I had to copy proguard-android.txt in as it wasn't included in proguard4.11.zip.